# Magento registry in widget's template returns null

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, session, widgets, registry

I'm trying to pass some data from controller thru redirection to widget's .phtml file.

In sampleController.php:

```
Mage::register('demo_access', (isset($request['paragraphText']) ? 2 : 1));
Mage::log(Mage::registry('demo_access'));
$this->_redirect('watchdemo.html');
```

Works well, but after redirection to some cms page with some widget in sample.phtml code:

```
<?php var_dump($this->getNameInLayout()); ?>
```

returns null. Is it possible to do my job using registry or should I use session for my task?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do my job using registry or should I use session for my task?

Use the session. The registry is only valid per request (the data is nothing but a big PHP array) and `_redirect()` results in a new request from your browser.